# Amazon LinuxにpyenvでPython2.6.9を入れようとするとBUILD ERRORになる

Tags: python, vagrant, python2, pyenv, amazon-linux

### はじめに

#### 環境

- OS: Amazon Linux version 2018.03
  (Vagrant/VirtualBoxによってMacOS上に用意した仮想環境、[mvbcoding/awslinux](https://app.vagrantup.com/mvbcoding/boxes/awslinux)を使用)
- Python: 2.7.12 (AWSに最初から入っていたPython)

#### 問題点

上記環境にpyenvを用いてPython2.6.9をインストールして動作確認テストしようとしました。

まず下記のようなコマンドを打ってpyenvをインストールした。

```
$ yum install git
$ git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
```

※この後、[pyenvを用いたpython環境構築手順（CentOS7.1）](https://qiita.com/ksugawara61/items/ba9a51ebfdaf8d1a1b48) を参考に `.bash_profile` も編集した

```
$ pyenv --version
pyenv 1.2.21
```

その後、pyenvを使ってPython2.6.9をインストールするためrootユーザーに入った上で `pyenv install 2.6.9` と打ったところ下記のエラーが出た。(`pyenv install --list`で2.6.9があるのは確認済。)

```
[root@localhost ~]# pyenv install 2.6.9
Downloading Python-2.6.9.tgz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.9/Python-2.6.9.tgz
Installing Python-2.6.9...
/root/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 1539: patch: command not found

BUILD FAILED (Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03 using python-build 1.2.21)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20201021084730.4215
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20201021084730.4215.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/python-build.20201021084730.4215 ~
/tmp/python-build.20201021084730.4215/Python-2.6.9 /tmp/python-build.20201021084730.4215 ~
```

その後に[pyenvのTroubleshooting](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki)を参考に、「CentOS/Fedora 21 and below:」と書かれている`yum install`を実行したが結果は下記のようだった。

```
[root@localhost ~]# pyenv install 2.6.9
Downloading Python-2.6.9.tgz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.9/Python-2.6.9.tgz
Installing Python-2.6.9...
/root/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 1539: patch: command not found

BUILD FAILED (Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03 using python-build 1.2.21)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20201021084900.4387
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20201021084900.4387.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/python-build.20201021084900.4387 ~
/tmp/python-build.20201021084900.4387/Python-2.6.9 /tmp/python-build.20201021084900.4387 ~
```

/tmpの中は下記のようになっていた。

```
python-build.20201021084730.4215      python-build.20201021084900.4387.log  vagrant-shell
python-build.20201021084730.4215.log  python-patch.mfYkoj                   vboxguest-Module.symvers
python-build.20201021084900.4387      python-patch.ZdyBkC
```

#### 質問

- 上記現象の原因は何でしょうか？
  ※logの中身を見ても原因が掴めません...
- 上記の解決方法はあるでしょうか？

以上、宜しくお願いします！

Comment: `patch: command not found` と表示されていますので `patch` コマンドがインストールされていません。

Comment: @metropolis ご指摘のとおりでした！(完全に見落とししていました...)アンサー承認したいので、回答の方に同内容書いていただけると有り難いです。

Comment: 一応回答にしてみましたが、Amazon Linux にはデフォルトで patch がインストールされていない、という現実に時代性？を感じる所ではあります。その点を鑑みますと、ソースコードをコンパイル・ビルドするのに必要となるかもしれないツールが他にもインストールされていないかもしれませんね。

Comment: 補足いただき有り難いです！(かなりレガシーなPython製システムの動作テストのために古めかしい仮想環境を構築しています。)一応pyenvのtroubleshootに載っているものを全てyum installすると問題なくPython2.6.9が入りました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyenv install` の実行結果の出力に、

> /root/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 1539: patch: command not found

と表示されていますので、`patch` コマンドがインストールされていないと思われます。

おそらく yum コマンドで `patch` パッケージをインストールすれば解決するかと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

metropolis さんの回答、およびコメントに対する補足です。

Amazon Linux で使用する `yum` コマンドは基本的に個別のパッケージ単位で指定しますが、オプションを使用することで関連するパッケージを「グループ」という単位で管理することができます。

具体的には `yum groupinstall` に続けてグループ名を指定します。

今回のようにソースコードのコンパイルが必要になるときには、"Development Tools" というグループを指定してインストールしておくと便利です。

**実行例:**

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

[Amazon Linux インスタンスでソフトウェアのコンパイルを準備する - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html)

> システムでソフトウェアのコンパイルを可能にするには、make、gcc、autoconf など、いくつかの開発ツールをインストールする必要があります。
>
> ソフトウェアのコンパイルはすべての Amazon EC2 インスタンスで必要なタスクではないため、そのようなツールはデフォルトでインストールされていません。ただし、「Development Tools」という名前のパッケージグループで利用でき、yum groupinstall コマンドでインスタンスに簡単に追加されます。

なお、どんなパッケージがインストールされるのかは、`yum groupinfo <GROUPNAME>` で一覧が確認できます。

**CentOS 7 での実行結果 (参考):**

```
$ sudo yum groupinfo "Development Tools"

グループ: 開発ツール
 グループ ID: development
 説明: 基本的な開発環境
 強制的なパッケージ:
    autoconf
    automake
    binutils
    bison
    flex
    gcc
    gcc-c++
    gettext
    libtool
    make
    patch
    pkgconfig
    redhat-rpm-config
    rpm-build
    rpm-sign
 標準パッケージ:
    byacc
    cscope
    ctags
    diffstat
    doxygen
    elfutils
    gcc-gfortran
    git
    indent
    intltool
    patchutils
    rcs
    subversion
    swig
    systemtap

 ～(以下略)～
```

**参考:**

[yumで関連パッケージをまとめて追加／削除するには - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/678yumgroup.html)